# PHP:Class not call

Tags: php, class

I've a class called parser located in Data\Dictionary and i call it to transform a string to object using this function:

```
Use Data\Dictionary\Parser as Parser;
function loadDictionary($conn) {

    $dictText=DictionaryAsTextString($conn);
     $parser = new Parser();

    try {
        $dict=$parser->parseDictionary ($dictText);

    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        echo "Erreurs";

    }
    return $dict;
}
```

However, it display this message:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Data\Dictionary\Parser' not found in C:\wamp64\www....\index.php on line 65
>   ( ! ) Error: Class 'Data\Dictionary\Parser' not found in C:\wamp64\www...\index.php on line 65

Please any help!

Comment: Have you included (manually or with autoload) a file with this class?

Comment: You have to use `require_once 'path/to/class.php', then you can use it.

Comment: Anyway, mixing the use of functions and classes is not a good choice. Maybe you may find helpful start learning PHP using a framework like Symfony (complex and advanced), Silex (simpler), Laravel (complex) or something else: this will give you an idea of how to structure your files, of the coding styles, best practices, etc...

Comment: This problem has been solved. Thanks to  @Aerendir . I'll use one of php framework in the next.